Is it true that the city of Kashi never gets destroyed even when the universe ends?
Is it true that the city of Kashi never gets destroyed during Pralay, MahaPralay or even when the Universe ends ?

Yeah, Kasi and Vrindavan, mentioned in devi baghavatham I think.

The pṛthvi itself is destroyed at kalpānta pralaya, let alone Kāśī, which is a sthāna on pṛthvi.

@Bingming No Kashi never gets destroyed, I have heard.

Yes, you are right. Kasi never gets destroyed. During the time of pralaya, Siva holds up this sacred place on his trident.
Kasi was created by Nirguna Siva even before the creation. It is the navel of the creation. Vishnu sleeps here. Brahma comes out of the navel of Vishnu. Then he starts creation.
Siva Purana, Kotirudra Samhita, Chapter 22

Hara himself released Kashika from his trident and brought it down on earth, in the world of the mortals. When Brahma’s day ends, it is certainly not destroyed. O sages! Shiva holds it up on his trident then. O brahmanas! When Brahma starts on his act of creation again, it is re-established.

